# How to view the size of an object in a tree view from a java program (similar as in eclipse mat)

Tags: java, debugging, serialization, wicket, eclipse-mat

I have a heapdump retrieved and opened with the Eclipse Memory Analyzer.

[image: serialized wicket page in mat]

Unfortunately a big part is represented by the serialized wicket page, I've done right click > Copy > Save Value To File, saved it on my desktop.

After this I've opened it in my application and deserialized the object.

[image: debug mode with IDEA]

Currently I've got only hints with Intellij IDEA memory view on the object counts.

My problem now is how can I view my deserialized object in a tree view with the memory allocation (absolute numbers or percentage) like in Eclipse Memory Analyzer?

Can I save the object to a heap dump again and view it in Eclipse Memory Analyzer?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the wicket-devutils project. Inside you will find a DebugBar which you can add just as any other component. It will show you an component graph including the exact memory allocation of any component in the component tree